# how to save and set window.pageYOffset with shadowbox.js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, shadowbox

inside a [shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com)'s box I have a long list of elements, I want that when I close the box and reopen it, the scrollbar goes at the same position I left it before. I found this library: [redips-scroll.js](http://www.redips.net/javascript/maintain-scroll-position/) that works with simple pages, not with shadowbox, in fact it catches the `window.pageYOffset` of the background page nor of the foreground one.
Is there a way to obtain the desired result also using another lightbox library that supports AJAX calls?

Comment: Could you make a demo (like on jsFiddle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing the way my page was built, shadowbox is not as good and opensource and flexible as [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), so I moved to it, more than this, [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) offers by default pagination and state save. So scr*w shadowbox, :.)

Linuxatico